# Why can't Quicktime play a movie file encoded by FFmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, quicktime

When I try to open a movie I just created with the command:

```
ffmpeg -pattern_type glob -i '*.JPG' -s 640x480 movie.mp4
```

I get an error from QuickTime:

```
The document “movie.mp4” could not be opened.
The file may be damaged or may not be a movie file that is compatible with QuickTime Player.
```

I used the same command on a set of images generated from an iSight time lapse, but in this case the above images are from a digital camera.  The resolution is a lot higher, but I am scaling it to 640x480 and I don't see anything in the output that suggests a problem:

```
Input #0, image2, from '*.JPG':
  Duration: 00:00:04.76, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p(pc), 4928x3264, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
```

vs. the working movie:

```
Input #0, image2, from '*.JPG':
  Duration: 00:01:23.72, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj420p(pc), 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
```

And for the output:

```
Output #0, mp4, to 'movie.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf55.19.104
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuvj422p, 640x480, q=-1--1, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg -> libx264)
```

vs. for the working one:

```
Output #0, mp4, to 'movie.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf55.19.104
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuvj420p, 640x480 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], q=-1--1, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mjpeg -> libx264)
```

Aside from the working movie being longer and a lower source resolution, the only difference I can see is that there is an extra "[SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3]" mentioned in the video stream, but I have no idea what this is, or how to try to force it in the non-working movie.

Update: I just downloaded VLC and it plays the movie fine.  So I know ffmpeg isn't at fault here.

Comment: For the future, when asking about ffmpeg, please always include the full, uncut command line output. It should have told you something about the pixel format not being compatible with some players, if I'm not mistaken (and if you have a recent version).

Comment: `ffprobe video.mp4` can be used to check which pixel format is used.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Based on this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14437323/117259) I would add `-pix_fmt yuv420p` to your command like this; [one of the comments mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14430593/encoding-a-readable-movie-by-quicktime-using-ffmpeg/14437323#comment20101285_14437323) adding `-vcodec libx264` as well so it’s included here:

```
ffmpeg -pattern_type glob -i '*.JPG' -vcodec libx264 -s 640x480 \
-pix_fmt yuv420p movie.mp4
```

Or you could use the [format filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#format). This example will use the [scale filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale) instead of `-s`, and the format filter instead of `-pix_fmt`:

```
ffmpeg -pattern_type glob -i '*.JPG' -vcodec libx264 \
-vf scale=640:-2,format=yuv420p movie.mp4
```

Also [elaborated on in the official FFmpeg Wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#Encodingfordumbplayers) under the heading “Encoding for dumb players”; emphasis mine:

> **You may need to use `-pix_fmt yuv420p` for your output to work in
>   QuickTime and most other players.** These players only supports the YUV
>   planar color space with 4:2:0 chroma subsampling for H.264 video.
>   Otherwise, depending on your source, ffmpeg may output to a pixel
>   format that may be incompatible with these players.

Comment: Indeed, ffmpeg was choosing the default encoding of yuv422p which upset Quicktime.  Adding `-pix_fmt yuv420p` solved it for me!