# Video created from ffmpeg can be played in desktop chrome but not mobile chrome?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, google-chrome, ffmpeg, android

I have a project that

1. generates a .jpg file with a caption (using imagemagick convert)
2. creates a .mp4 file by combining the .jpg file from step 1 and an .aac audio file
3. concatenates several videos from step 2 into one large .mp4 file.

It all works well enough but what I'm finding now is that the final combined .mp4 file from step 3 plays just fine in Windows via Chrome or VLC or whatever. But when I try to watch the same video on my phone using android/chrome, it doesn't seem to know how to play it.

I'm sure it's something with framerates (step 1 above?) or encoding or something, but does anybody have any hints that'll get me steered in the right direction? Just can't seem to figure it out. The server this is all happening on is Ubuntu Server 20.04.

Comment: Make sure it is really an MP4 video, nut just the file extension. Check the bitrate, bit depth (8/10bit) and also the encoding profile (normal/high). Also the used Android device has impact (supported hardware acceleration).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was self-solved by the author with this post on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17379971/117259).

Answer (score -1):

I guess my google-fu just hadn't woken up yet when I posted this. I finally got it solved by following the answer in this page.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17379971/html5-video-chrome-ffmpeg-mp4-working-in-all-but-chrome

Comment: Sorry to say this isn’t an answer. Since you posted it as a link only answer. That said, you can make this answer and actual answer by clearly stating the info about the `-pix_fmt yuv420p` setting in the options. And past any of that, the answer is somewhat of a duplicate of [this answer I posted about 8 years back](https://superuser.com/a/820137/167207). That answer was for a question about QuickTime, but the solution is the same. So this thread could maybe be a Chrome-specific thread with that info? Your call but as is this question is a link only answer.

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.